# Using anchor tag with React router and avoid page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We show a grid to users with product info. The first column is supposed to show a link to take the user to another route that displays product details. The grid component we use, accepts a template for cell. So we can provide something like this:

```
<a href='/product-details/{row.productId}'>{row.productName}</a>
```

This renders fine and the link is fine too. However, when the product name is clicked it reloads the page. We cannot use Link tag here.

Is there a way to form a link manually using the anchor tag - how the react-router's Link element creates links?

Please note that we want to use [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter). If we use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter), we can form the links with /#/ and the page doesn't reload. However, we want to avoid using HashRouter.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what's wrong with using a `<Link />` tag here ... ?

Comment: Agreed, a `Link` renders an `<a />` under the hood.

Comment: These "templates" are coming from a legacy system and contain an anchor tag. They're also consumed by another system. We can't  convert them to Link tags. So coming back to the ques, is it possible to not refresh the page is anchor tag is used.